# Browser error says "Cannot add property *, object is not extensible" - Even though property does exist in the class definition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I using React w/Sails.js backend. I think this question really only pertains to React/javascript.

I am getting the following browser console error even though the property being changed does exist in the object:

`Cannot add property *, object is not extensible`

Below is the class definition and the error occurs in the use of:

`onExchangeSelect={selectedExchange => this.setState({selectedExchange})`

in the render function below. That is, the browser complains the object is not extensible and gives that lines as the reason (and when I remove the onExchangeSelect function the error goes away).

```
class ExchangeContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      exchanges:[
        {
          name:"binance",
          url:"https://bittrex.com"
        },
        {
          name:"bittrex",
          url:"https://bittrex.com"
        }
      ],
      selectedExchange:null
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ExchangeContainer list-group">
        <ExchangeList
            exchanges={this.state.exchanges} selected={this.state.selectedExchange}
            onExchangeSelect={selectedExchange => this.setState({selectedExchange}) }
        />
        <ExchangeDetail exchange={this.state.selectedExchange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My question, what might be causing the error and subsequent failure for the React component to render? Why can't I change that property?

Answer (score 0):

Try to spread/copy the object (otherwise, it is just using same memory location).

```
onExchangeSelect={selectedExchange => 
     this.setState({
        selectedExchange: {...selectedExchange}
     })
 }
```

Comment: Same result. I used your syntax above.

Comment: Then, share the details of `onExchangeSelect` method.

Comment: I believe that this line:

`onExchangeSelect={selectedExchange => this.setState({selectedExchange}) }`

Means onExchangeSelect is the function defined by the stuff next to it wherein it sets the state. That function is then passed into the ExchangeList React component (which then passes it to another component for callback), but to answer your question I believe the definition is included:

`{selectedExchange => this.setState({selectedExchange}) }`

But I am very new to javascript, React and ES6.

Comment: Is array of `exchanges` contain simple object? or deep level object (deep level means nested object)?

Comment: The exchanges array is hard coded in the constructor above:

this.state = {
      exchanges:[..

Comment: Ok I have resolved the initial error...although I'm not sure how exactly...